# Get the count of rows for each month in specific date range

Tags: mysql, database

I have list of records in table `A` and want to get the count of records for each month in range of days, starting from first of this month to the current day. So if we have 3 months and the current day is 19, So for the first month i need count of records between 1st to 19th of the month, and for the second month from 1st to 19th and so on.

```
id     time                 
1      2005-07-05 14:10:29
2      2005-07-12 15:47:35
3      2005-08-02 16:38:53
4      2005-08-04 10:48:12
5      2006-08-22 17:34:28
6      2006-09-01 22:11:35
7      2006-09-09 15:10:19
8      2006-09-06 21:55:56
```

The desired Result:

```
time       count
2005-07     2
2005-08     2
2006-09     3
```

we ignored the record id 5 because we just count the days between 1st and 19th for each month.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cam filter the rows with the function [`DAY()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day) and aggregate:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m') yearmonth,
       COUNT(*) counter
FROM tablename
WHERE DAY(time) <= DAY(CURRENT_DATE)
GROUP BY yearmonth
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2a17dce16806137ea76c51319637605f).
Results:

| yearmonth | counter |
| --- | --- |
| 2005-07 | 2 |
| 2005-08 | 2 |
| 2006-09 | 3 |